# Hint that the type of a method's return-value is a class type

Tags: python, types, type-hinting

How can I hint that the type of a method's return-value is a class type?

For example:

```
def myMethod(x: int, y: str) -> object:
    ...
```

Does `object` hint that the method returns an instance of some class (i.e., does it hint that the type of the method's return-value is a class type)?

I've searched for the `object` keyword on the official documentation, but I haven't been able to find a straightforward answer to this.

here is a more concrete example of the problem which I am trying to solve:

```
from type1 import Type1
from type2 import Type2
from type3 import Type3

factory = {
    'xxx': {'type': Type1, 'args': {'a': 1, 'b': 2}},
    'yyy': {'type': Type2, 'args': {'c': 'sssssss'}},
    'zzz': {'type': Type3, 'args': {'d': False}},
}

def createObj(name: str) -> object:
    template = factory[name]
    return template['type'](template['args'])
```

I am asking if `object` is the most accurate hint to use here.

Comment: **everything** is an instance of some class. So yes, `object` does guarantee that I guess (since everything is ultimately an instance of `object`). but can you elaborate on what, exactly, you are trying to accomplish?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga: Well, I want to hint of something which is not a built-in type like `int` or `str` or `dict`, but rather, a class type defined by the programmer (and not by the language).

Comment: ... then you use that type. Again, `int`, `str`, and `dict` *are classes* just as much as `class Foo: pass` is a class. So if you `return Foo()` then the type annotation should probably be `Foo`. Classes *themeslves* are instances of classes too! Of metaclasses

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga: My method's return value may be of different types, all of which being user-defined class types. Is there anything in the language standard which makes these types distinct from built-in types? Your comment above implies that the `object` and `any` keywords are essentially identical in nature.

Comment: neither `object` nor `any` are keywords in python. I am assuming you mean `typing.Any`, and that means something very different than `object`. `typing.Any` basically means "don't type check this".

Comment: So, suppose I havea. `def foo() -> object` and `def bar() -> Any:`, then `x = foo(); x + 1` will fail, but `x = bar(), x + 1` will pass the type checker

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga: I am able to use both `object` and `any` without importing anything. Doesn't that mean that they are a built-in part of the language?

Comment: Anyway, no, in Python's type system, there is no distinction between built-in types and user-defined types. how would that distinction even be useful? It sounds liek you may want to annotate your type to return a *union* of some types

Comment: `any` is **not the same thing as `typing.Any`**. And being a built-in part of the language doesn't mean it's a keyword. A key word, by definition, is a word that cannot be used as a name. So, for example, `for` is a keyword. You cannot do `for = 42`, that will raise a SyntaxError

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga: OK, so putting semantics aside for a moment, is there any way to hint that the return-value type is a user-defined class type?

Comment: I don't know how to be any more clear, no there isn't.

Comment: Again, you probably just want a union, using the most up-to-date syntax, say you have `class Foo`, `class Bar`, and `class Baz`, then you want to specify your return type as `-> Foo | Bar | Baz`, although, perhaps, it should be a bound type variable. again, it really would help if you elaborated on your actual use-case

Comment: Your edit makes it clear that what you probably want is either class union, as @juanpa.arrivillaga suggested, or, probably a better choice, make all the Types inherit from common interface - that way you don't need to change the return typing later should you want to handle another class.

Comment: so, yeah, you want `-> Type1 | Type2 | Type3`, however, you maybe be able to use `typing.overload` to get better type resolution (unions are generally not great, especially as return types, since to do most things with them you often need to check the type). Do you expect to always use a literal string expression when calling `createObj`, e.g. `createObj("yyy")` or potentially, do you have `x = input()` then `createObj(x)`

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga: They are also not supported until Python 3.10, from what I see. Anyways, I guess that a more object-oriented solution would be to inherit all from the same class (which I actually did, but was reluctant to import that class only for the sake of hinting it, so was hoping for an alternative way). Thanks!

Comment: @bbbbbbbbb Check my edit for pre 3.10 equivalent, although I think object oriented solution is a better one.

Comment: @bbbbbbbbb you can use `typing.Union` instead.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to hint that the return value of your method is an instance of a class, you should use the class name itself as the type hint. Here's an example:

```
class MyClass:
    ...

def myMethod(x: int, y: str) -> MyClass:
    ...
```

In this way is also more redable the code, since a developer can understand also which specific class is returned by the function

Comment: That would bound `myMethod` to returning only one specific class type, which is not what I'm interested in, since my method's return value may be of different types (all class types though).

Comment: @bbbbbbbbb what you are asking doesn't make any sense. Again, can you please elaborate on what exactly you are trying to accomplish? What is the real problem you are trying to solve?

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga: My method's return value may be of different types, all of which being user-defined class types. Is there anything in the language standard which makes these types distinct from built-in types?

Comment: @bbbbbbbbb no, and that distinction wouldn't be useful. it sounds like you want some sort of union. Again, it is really important for you to edit your question and elaborate on your actual use-case

Answer (score 0):

After taking your edit into account which makes it completely different question, I'd suggest 2 possible options:
One is to mark the return type as union of all the handled classes:

```
class Type1:
    pass
class Type2:
    pass
class Type3:
    pass

factory = {
    'xxx': {'type': Type1, 'args': {'a': 1, 'b': 2}},
    'yyy': {'type': Type2, 'args': {'c': 'sssssss'}},
    'zzz': {'type': Type3, 'args': {'d': False}},
}

def createObj(name: str) -> Type1 | Type2 | Type3:
    template = factory[name]
    return template['type'](template['args'])
```

Note: pre-3.10 equivalent syntax is `-> typing.Union[Type1, Type2, Type3]:`

The other, probably better one is to make all the classes share some kind of interface (maybe even a null one), and type your function with that interface:

```
class Interface:
    pass
class Type1(Interface):
    pass
class Type2(Interface):
    pass
class Type3(Interface):
    pass

factory = {
    'xxx': {'type': Type1, 'args': {'a': 1, 'b': 2}},
    'yyy': {'type': Type2, 'args': {'c': 'sssssss'}},
    'zzz': {'type': Type3, 'args': {'d': False}},
}

def createObj(name: str) -> Interface:
    template = factory[name]
    return template['type'](template['args'])
```

This way every class inheriting from interface will be valid return value, so you don't need to remember updating that value every time you want to handle a new type.

Answer (score 0):

So, here is a simplified example of how I would handle the general case. I would overload the type annotation using literal types and unions.

```
import typing

class Foo:
    pass

class Bar:
    pass

class Baz:
    pass


factory: dict[str, type[Foo | Bar | Baz]] = {
    "xxx": Foo,
    "yyy": Bar,
    "zzz": Baz,
}


@typing.overload
def create_obj(x: typing.Literal['xxx']) -> Foo:
    ...
@typing.overload
def create_obj(x: typing.Literal['yyy']) -> Bar:
    ...
@typing.overload
def create_obj(x: typing.Literal['zzz']) -> Baz:
    ...
@typing.overload
def create_obj(x: str) -> Foo | Bar | Baz:
    ...
def create_obj(x: str) -> Foo | Bar | Baz:
    return factory[x]()


s = create_obj(input())
reveal_type(s)

x = create_obj("xxx")
reveal_type(x)

y = create_obj("yyy")
reveal_type(y)

z = create_obj("zzz")
reveal_type(z)
```

The output of `mypy` here is:

```
test.py:37: note: Revealed type is "Union[test.Foo, test.Bar, test.Baz]"
test.py:40: note: Revealed type is "test.Foo"
test.py:43: note: Revealed type is "test.Bar"
test.py:46: note: Revealed type is "test.Baz"
Success: no issues found in 1 source file
```

So note, in the cases where we have some unknown `str` (e.g. from `input()`), it infers the return type as the union, but when we use a literal expression, we can get the *exact* type we expect!

Note, on older versions of Python, you may need to use `typing.Type` instead of `type` and you may need to use `typing.Union[Foo, Bar, Baz]` instead of `Foo | Bar | Baz`